# How to save each user's index from Llama index to PostgreSQL database in chatGPT clone app

Tags: reactjs, django, postgresql, openai-api, llama-index

I am trying to make a chatGPT clone that can answer on external data (private data) using React, Django, OpenAI API, PostgreSQL, and Llama index, precisely speaking, in context learning.

Then, my question is, how can I save each user's data (= index in the context of llama index)to PostgreSQL database? I Would like to know which method to store the data in the database is suitable in this case.

I find it difficult to store a file or a folder to the database...